# Design Patterns for the manipulation of search results

Tags: design-patterns

I'm developing an application which makes extensive use of search results, including handling of filters, manual query expansion and annotations. Do you know any related design patterns specifically for this purpose? (the more language independent the better)
Have you ever applied any of the classic GoF design patterns for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned GoF I will assume you are asking for Object-Oriented design patterns and not EAA, EAI or SOAP patterns. Search design patterns are mostly related with the developement of adaptive systems, and there is significative research in such area. Using keywords as "self-adaptive systems", "autonomic computing", "continuous query" you can find interesting results although not in the Pattern Template form.

If you are not working with distributed systems, there is a research group which publishes approaches [[1](http://www.dcc.ufla.br/infocomp/images/artigos/v10.2/art05.pdf), [2](http://www.indianjournals.com/ijor.aspx?target=ijor:ijaritac&volume=2&issue=2&article=008), [3]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6145158) in the context of DSS and noisy data: (from the Abstract)

*"In this paper we propose and describe a new design pattern called FTI (Filter - Trender - Interpretation) for interpreting noisy and voluminous data sets. FTI consists of 3 consecutive processes: Filter which takes the original data and removes outliers and noise; given large volumes of data, Trender takes the filtered data and abstracts trends; and Interpretation uses rules from knowledge bases to perform qualitative reasoning on the trends to provide an analysis of the original data. In this paper we also show how FTI has been successfully applied to two different case studies."*

Another pattern frequently cited is Blackboard, but it is a pattern used in Pattern Languages.

An application from which you can review applied search patterns is [@Note: A workbench for Biomedical Text Mining](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046409000537)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a classic pattern, but it could helps:

> [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it seems to be a more general design pattern and since the search result problem is a very popular problem I thought some very related patterns would emerge.